# How to order MySQL output using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

With the MYSQL functions being depreciated I've been trying to move my code to PDO, but there are a couple of features I've got used to with SQL that I can't replicate in PDO.
Here's my code for printing out a table that contains information from Twitter:

```
<?php $date = date('H:i:s', time()); ?>
<h3>Twitter Feed @ <?php echo "$date"; ?></h3>

<?php
/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'localhost';

/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'MySQL_USER';

/*** mysql password ***/
$password = 'SECRET';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=DB_NAME", $username, $password);
    /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
    echo 'Printing Tweets<br />';

    /*** The SQL SELECT statement ***/

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tweets";
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
       {
        print $row['created_at'] .' <br /> '. $row['tweet_text'] .' <br /> '.     $row['screen_name'] . ' <br /> '. $row['name'] .' <br /> '. '<br /><br />';
    }

/*** close the database connection ***/
$dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
 ?>
```

Three questions:

**This code outputs the first Tweet stored first. How do I order it so the last Tweet is first?**

In MYSQL I would write

`$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tweets ORDER BY`created_at`DESC");`

**The table contains a link to the users picture, how would I print that out as a image instead of text?**

Again, in MySQL I would write:

```
    echo "<img src='";
echo stripslashes($row[9]);
echo "'>";
```

**Rather than having to remember passwords and usernames I've always put the connection details in a seperate include file - such as database_connection.php - which is password protected. Is this possible in PDO?**

In MySQL:

```
require_once 'includes/database_connection.php' ;
```

Comment: I think your confusing MySQL with PHP

Comment: XSS alarm: please use `htmlspecialchars` when outputting user data to HTML. And do you really need `stripslashes`?

Comment: Mysql functions are part of PHP, and will be deprecated in later versions - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php - so I'm trying to get away from MySQL functions before that happens.

Comment: I use Stripslashes on all my img links because of how some are stored. I guess I don't need them here, but it's habit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mysql language hasn't changed, just how you access the database. The ORDER BY statement will still work as is. By changing this line:

```
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
```

To this:

```
foreach ($dbh->query($sql,PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row)
```

you can access each column by column name, as you did before.

Your image link would only change in how you access the column:

```
echo stripslashes($row['image']); // Or whatever the column name is
```

And the connection database file will still be fine.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Not sure why the database file is failing, thought it might be processing the twitter page before the database connection file and so stopping as it wasn't connected. Will try again.